# Determine time gaps in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to self learn the lag and lead functions and thought I would try it with the following report but I'm not having much luck. My goal is to take some on-call start and stop times for a department and create a report detailing the time gaps for the day that there was no coverage. The department is assumed to have 24 hour coverage, 7 days a week. Is the only way to handle this to join it to a datetime table that has the date and every minute available? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The expected outcome for the data below would be:

```
on 09/01/2020 dept 3042300031 had a time gap from 20:59 to 21:00 and a time gap from 22:59 to 23:59
on 09/02/2020 dept 3042300031 had a time gap from 00:00 to 00:05 and a time gap from 20:59 to 22:00 and a time gap from 22:50 to 23:59
on 09/03/2020 dept 3042300031 had a time gap from 00:00 to 23:59
on 09/04/2020 dept 3042300031 had a time gap from 20:59 to 23:59
```

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#report') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #report
GO

CREATE TABLE #report (
 Contact_Date date
,Line   int
,Start_Instant_dttm smalldatetime
,End_Instant_dttm datetime
,Asgn_to_Role   int
,Asgn_to_Team   bigint
);

INSERT INTO #report
SELECT
'9/1/2020',1,'9/1/2020 00:00','9/1/2020 20:59',270,3042300031
UNION
SELECT
'9/1/2020',2,'9/1/2020 21:00','9/1/2020 22:59',270,3042300031
UNION
SELECT
'9/2/2020',1,'9/2/2020 00:05','9/2/2020 20:59',270,3042300031
UNION
SELECT
'9/2/2020',2,'9/2/2020 22:00','9/2/2020 22:59',270,3042300031
UNION
SELECT
'9/4/2020',1,'9/4/2020 00:00','9/4/2020 20:59',270,3042300031;
```

Comment: Please add expected result how it should look like and what is 24:00 ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look here: [sql - gaps and islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Comment: Yep brain fart on the 2400 changed it to 2359. As far as what I have tried so far. I had tried something similar to dnoeth's first cte where I was getting the time gaps between the on calls but was having issues with the calendar days; thus my mention of joining to a datetime table. Which dnoeth seems to only joined to a date table.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the gaps is simple:

```
with cte as
 ( 
   select Asgn_to_Team, Start_Instant_dttm, End_Instant_dttm
      ,lag(End_Instant_dttm) 
       over (partition by Asgn_to_Team
             order by Start_Instant_dttm) as prev_end
   from #report
 )
select Asgn_to_Team, prev_end as gap_start, Start_Instant_dttm as gap_end
from cte
where prev_end < Start_Instant_dttm
```

But splitting them into days is much harder, you need to join to a calendar table:

```
with cte as
 ( 
   select Asgn_to_Team, Start_Instant_dttm, End_Instant_dttm
      ,lag(End_Instant_dttm) 
       over (partition by Asgn_to_Team
             order by Start_Instant_dttm) as prev_end
   from #report
 )
select Asgn_to_Team, 
   case when prev_end > cast(cal.cal_date as datetime)
        then prev_end
        else cast(cal.cal_date as datetime)
   end as gap_start,
   case when Start_Instant_dttm < cast(dateadd(day, 1, cal.cal_date) as datetime)
        then Start_Instant_dttm
        else cast(dateadd(day, 1, cal.cal_date) as datetime)
   end as gap_end
from cte join cal -- one row for each date covered
  on cast(cal.cal_date as datetime) <= Start_Instant_dttm
 and cast(dateadd(day, 1, cal.cal_date) as datetime) > prev_end
where prev_end < Start_Instant_dttm
```

Hopefully I got the >/< right, see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2cf0b137507caf3cdef405cc23dff4e)

Comment: Thanks the cte is where I was at but I was trying to join it to a table broken by time( by minute) and date, was not working. I'll create a calendar table and see how yours works. Thanks